# Unable to connect jupyter notebook on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook

I have trouble connecting jupyter notebook on AWS. I tried several solutions on SO, including setting security group rule with port 8888 from any ip, setting configure file like:

```
c = get_config()

# Notebook config this is where you saved your pem cert
c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/home/ubuntu/certs/mycert.pem' 
# Run on all IP addresses of your instance
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
# Don't open browser by default
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False  
# Fix port to 8888
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
```

Also, I tried using `jupyter notebook --ip=my_aws_ip --port=8888`. For the login part, I use `ssh -i <pem key> ubuntu@<ec2...> -L 8888:localhost:8888` All above solutions returned `https://ip-172-31-44-200:8888/?token=******`, and I was not able to open this url in the web browser, saying that `ip-172-31-44-200’s server IP address could not be found.`.

Is there any solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the private IP of the Ec2 you are trying to access. You should use either the DNS or the Public IP on port `8888`.

Comment: @AlexK Do you know how I should use DNS or the public IP to connect notebook? I changed the url with the public IP, but it returned the same thing.

Comment: Make sure your ec2 is accessible by your IP, I.e. adjust your security group and check the firewall of the machine

Comment: @AlexK Got it, thanks!

Comment: Did you connect? If you have I will add it as an answer so others can benefit too :)

Comment: @AlexK yep. I will add the answer to help people who may also have the same issue:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @AlexK mentioned in the comments, I should use DNS or the public IP to connect jupyter notebook. For people who have the same issue, under the AWS instance tab, you can find the Public DNS (IPv4), then connect jupyter notebook using `jupyter notebook --ip=ec2-**.******.compute.amazonaws.com`. Now jupyter notebook should run perfectly on AWS.